# Web Crawler - object not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-crawler, html-agility-pack

I am developing a web crawler in asp.net.

My web-crawler has a main page from which it opens other HTML pages from HREF tags, downloads the HTML page and fetches the data.

The problem now is sometimes I get an exception of object reference not found sometimes the code works perfectly.

Is it because the asp.net buffer memory is full? If you want I can show you my code.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to debug your code. There is some code of your project or some library you are using that is not right checking if a object is null before using it.

Try this:

1. On Visual Studio
2. On the Debug menu, click Exceptions.
3. In the Exceptions dialog box, select Thrown for 'Common Language Runtime Exceptions'.
4. Start debugging (F5).
5. When the exception is throw, VS will break and it will show what is the possible code line with the problem.

More in [How to: Break When an Exception is Thrown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx)